# Webservice works on Android but not on IOS

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have written the below service in Angular 4. When I try to consume it 
on Android it works, but on IOS I get error status: 0  for URL: null
Need to know if something is wrong in web-service code?

```
getConversationData(userText : string){

    let userName = 'XYZ'
    let meetingType = 'ABC'
    let url = 'serverURL' + '/Conversation'

    return this.http.post( 
      url, 
      {
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json charset=UTF-8',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'},
        "message" : userText,
        "username" : userName,
        "MeetingType" : meetingType
      },

    ).map(response => response.json())
  }
```

Comment: which webview are you using in IOS? WKWebView?

Comment: if so..it is a CORS issue..

Comment: Yes I am using WKWebView view. How to solve this cors issue?

Answer (score 0):

WkWebView enforces [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) unlike the older UIWebView in IOS. Ionic is switching to this as a part of IOS 11 changes.

You will need to ensure your server-side API returns `Origin: http:localhost:8080` in the response header.(depends on the technology you are using to implement API).

Or use [ionic-native/http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) plugin to get around it.

Check docs WKWebView Documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#cors).

Answer (score 0):

Another area I've had to adjust in these types of scenarios is whitelisting resources so that the app allows access.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

See the `<allow-intent>` and `<allow-navigation>` areas.  I believe the ionic/cordova build process will inspect these and update the iOS plist.info file with this info too.